# Alternative to inner join to filter in datatable

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable and I would like to select first entry per day where all `curveIDs` are present. The only way I could think of to do this is with a join because then it will automatically join only where both datasets are present.

Here is what I have so far:

```
//core data from sql (I have little control over this)
DataTable ds = new DataTable(); 
da.Fill(ds);

//creating dataset with various tables based on curveIDs I look for
System.Data.DataSet dataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
            for (int i = 0; i < curveIds.Length; i++)
            {
                    dataSet.Tables.Add(ds.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<short>("curveID") == curveIds[i]).CopyToDataTable());
            }

//lets say I have two only and then I join them like this to match timestamps correctly
var result = from table1 in dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                         join table2 in dataSet.Tables[1].AsEnumerable() 
                         on table1["Timestamp"] equals table2["Timestamp"]
                         select new
                         {
                             Timestamp = (DateTime)table1["Timestamp"],
                             Spread = (double)table1["mid"] - 0.4 * (double)table2["mid"],
                             Power = (double)table1["mid"]
                         };

//lastly I do a firstordefault over the data as I only want the first timestamp where both are present (this step doesnt return the correct data)
var endres = result.OrderBy(a => a.Timestamp).GroupBy(a => a.Timestamp.ToShortDateString()).FirstOrDefault().ToList();
```

This seems very convoluted. The last step also does not return one recordset per day early in the morning but rather many datasets for one day.

In the full problem I would have to do this for 4-6 `curveIDs` which means I would have to do a variable number of joins which kind of makes this approach unfeasible.

Source data has the columns (`Timestamp`, `CurveID`, `Mid`) for each minute between 8am and 4pm on workdays but there is no guarantee that all `curveIDs` are actually there on every timestamp.

Lets say on day 1 at 8:01 all IDs are there (first time stamp where this is true but not only) and on day two only at 8:03 are all IDs there then the return data should be:

```
Day1 8:01, spread =x, Power=y
Day2 8:03, spread =z, Power=a
...
```

... and so forth, for every day only one entry chosen as the first where all IDs are there.

Comment: the last step doesnt return one dataset per day early in the morning but rather many datasets for each day. Problem is in the full problem I would have to join 4-6 tables on each other and I also dont always know whehter it is 4 or 6 which makes this difficult

Comment: So you don't have control to input a SQL query directly to DB?

Comment: I can but that is just transferring the problem to t-sql no?

Comment: Pretty much. But at least you're not loading a LOT of data in memory for this kind of operation.

Comment: Can you post a sample table structure, sample input and expected output. It's quite hard to understand what are you trying to achieve from what you posted currently.

Comment: Why do you have separate data tables for each curve ID?  If you can control the query, I'd definitely do it there.  When you group the results, you can keep only those groups where the number of rows in the group matches the expected number of curve IDs.  You might need to have a CTE to calculate the initial groups, then group those results by date and take the min time value to get exactly what you want.  Am I making sense?  If not, provide the additional information requested by Ivan above to get a more specific answer.

Comment: W/o some cooperation, the question will not receive enough attention even with bounty. See my previous comment.

Comment: @nik - Ivan's comments are quite important. You would have many good quality answers by now if you provided what's he's asked for. Have a ready of [ask] and [mcve] too.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, you want to find the lowest timestamp of every day (in the datatable you have) that have all the "curveIDs" of you curveID list?

If so, then I have wrote a code that might solve it. If there is a mistake, let me know in comments. Working with lists is easier to understand than sets o datatables. So I just used you "ds" datatable and built a indenpendt code.

Also there is optimizations to make, but that would let code a bit more hard to understand.

```
List<object> endress = new List<object>();

        //filter all timestamps, getting only the date info
        var timeStamps = ds.AsEnumerable().Select(r=> ((DateTime)r["Timestamp"]).Date).Distinct();

        //for each id
        foreach (var timeStamp in timeStamps)
        {
            //find all the same timestamp (on the same day)
            var listSameTimestamp = ds.AsEnumerable().Where(r => ((DateTime)r["Timestamp"]).Date == timeStamp);

            var listIds = listSameTimestamp.Select(r => (int)r["curveID"]).Distinct();

            //ensure they all have the curveIDs you are looking for
            var haveThemAll = curveIds.Intersect(listIds).Count() == curveIds.Count();

            if (haveThemAll == false)
                continue;

            //find the lowest timestamp
            var rowFound = listSameTimestamp.OrderBy(r => (DateTime)r["Timestamp"]).FirstOrDefault();
            if (rowFound == null)
                continue;

            //create an anonymous object (coud not understand your needs)
            endress.Add(new
            {
                Timestamp = (DateTime)rowFound["Timestamp"],
                Spread = (double)rowFound["mid"] - 0.4 * (double)rowFound["mid"],
                Power = (double)rowFound["mid"]
            });                   
        }
```

That is the "main" fragment. But you can see a whole test code here:

```
DataTable ds = new DataTable();
List<int> curveIds = new List<int>() {1,2,3,4};

public void Test()
{
    LoadDs();

    List<object> endress = new List<object>();

    //filter all timestamps, getting only the date info
    var timeStamps = ds.AsEnumerable().Select(r=> ((DateTime)r["Timestamp"]).Date).Distinct();

    //for each id
    foreach (var timeStamp in timeStamps)
    {
        //find all the same timestamp (on the same day)
        var listSameTimestamp = ds.AsEnumerable().Where(r => ((DateTime)r["Timestamp"]).Date == timeStamp);

        var listIds = listSameTimestamp.Select(r => (int)r["curveID"]).Distinct();

        //ensure they all have the curveIDs you are looking for
        var haveThemAll = curveIds.Intersect(listIds).Count() == curveIds.Count();

        if (haveThemAll == false)
            continue;

        //find the lowest timestamp
        var rowFound = listSameTimestamp.OrderBy(r => (DateTime)r["Timestamp"]).FirstOrDefault();
        if (rowFound == null)
            continue;

        //create an anonymous object (coud not understand your needs)
        endress.Add(new
        {
            Timestamp = (DateTime)rowFound["Timestamp"],
            Spread = (double)rowFound["mid"] - 0.4 * (double)rowFound["mid"],
            Power = (double)rowFound["mid"]
        });                   
    }


    foreach (var o in endress)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(o);
    }
}

public void LoadDs()
{
    ds = new DataTable();
    ds.Columns.Add("curveID",typeof(int));
    ds.Columns.Add("Timestamp", typeof(DateTime));
    ds.Columns.Add("mid", typeof(double));

    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
    {
        Random rand = new Random(i);
        var row = ds.NewRow();
        row["curveID"] = rand.Next(1,5);
        row["Timestamp"] = new  DateTime(2016,4, rand.Next(1,5), rand.Next(1,3), 0,0);
        row["mid"] = rand.NextDouble();

        ds.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:
 1. You have a table with timestamp, curveid, mid columns
 2. timestamps are (at least typically) every minute, not all curveids are guaranteed present
 3. You wish to calculate a spread, power using the rows for the first timestamp where all requisite curveids are present

I suggest something like this:

```
// I'll pretend the curveids are in this list...
List<double> curveids = new List<double>();

DataTable table = ds.Tables["Your table"];

// first get a grouping of timestamps for the day containing all curveids
// setup mindate and maxdate of your choosing...
var grouping = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => curveids.Contains(x.curveid) && 
                x.timestamp > mindate &&
                x.timestamp < maxdate)
    .GroupBy(x => x.timestamp);
// this gives a grouping of IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime, YourRowType>> 
// i.e. timestamps, and group of rows for each with curveids in your selection

// Now get the minimum timestamp, where all curve ids are present..
DateTime minTimestamp = grouping.Where(x => x.Count(y => y.curveid) == curveids.Count)
                                .Select(x => x.Key).Min();

// .. now can do what you wish with that...
// For example:
var resultRows = table.AsEnumerable().Where(x => 
                    x.timestamp == minTimestamp &&
                    curveids.Contains(x.Close));
```

Now you can use the resultRows and calculate the spread, power, etc or whatever depending upon the formula

Comment: This all makes sense and you understood perfectly. However, I have a  few problems: a) I need to work with Field<short>("CurveID"), I cannot get to grab the column as variable. b) If I try to find the min timestamp from grouping I seem to have lost even the column information all together.

Comment: Short should be System.Int16 in .net, I guess, so, if this works...
Int16 curveId = datarow.Field<System.Int16>("CurveID"), we should be able to modify the code to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it:

```
    //selecting into an object for better readability and access
    var result = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => new
    {
        TimeStamp = r.Field<DateTime>("TimeStamp"),
        CurveID = r.Field<short>("CurveId"),
        Mid = r.Field<double>("Mid")
    })
    // ignoring rows with different curve ID than in the list
    .Where(item => ids.Contains(item.CurveID))
    // grouping by timestamp
    .GroupBy(item => item.TimeStamp)
    // selecting only groups that have all curve Ids
    .Where(g => g.Select(i=>i.CurveID).Distinct().Count() == ids.Count)
    // grouping the groups by date
    .GroupBy(g => g.Key.Date)
    .Select(g2 =>
    {
        // getting the first timestamp group by timestamp
        var min = g2.OrderBy(i => i.Key).First();
        // getting all the Mid values
        var values = min.Select(i => i.Mid).ToList();
        // returning the desired computation
        return new
        {
            TimeStamp = min.Key,
            Spread = spread(values),
            Power = power(values)
        };
    })
    .ToList();
```

My assumptions from the text of the question and the existing comments are:

- timestamps must be exactly equal for all curve ids for the record to be taken into account
- records with curve ids that are not in the list are ignored
- only the mid values and the smallest timestamp where all curve ids
  meet each day matter to the end result

I have to add that this is not the most efficient method, as there are several passes that go through the data: first to group by timestamp and to filter by ids, then to filter by curveids, then to group by date and finally to first the first timestamp in the day. A faster but less readable implementation would order first, then only pass once through each item.